# visual studio 2013 iOS code signing

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to deploy an application from visual studio 2013 to my iPad using vs-mda-remote

The project  output is returning
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I know the provisioning profiles are OK on my Mac as i can build from xcode with out any issue.

But i'd like to try and work from visual studio for one project and i cannot get even the most basic of projects to build.

> MDAVSCLI : Code Sign warning : Can't locate the specified Code Signing Resource Rules file ('"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/ResourceRules.plist"').

Any help greatly appreciated - i've spent ages looking as well recreating all my apple certificates and profiles.

Thanks
John

Comment: "Workaround" follows but not calling this an answer. I have same issue. ResourceRules.plist exists at path specified. Xcode 6.2|Preferences|Accounts|View Details shows signing identities for iOS Development & iOS Distribution, and provisioning profile is there. Can build from VS and deploy to simulator on Mac but cannot deploy to Mac connected device. A work-around I am using is to manually open the generated xcodeproj file on the Mac, build, and deploy to device. The xcodeproj (and rest of the app source) will be in path /Users/uuuuu/remote-builds/builds/nnnnn/cordovaApp/platforms/ios.

Comment: I have used this method - but then editing the code and rebuilding in Xcode does not always force the files to be updated in the new deployed version. i seem to have to edit the files in the iOS version rather than at the cordova folder level... its a weird problem and i've just learnt to live with it.